# Why does response to my Java GET request have fewer headers than the same URL for Curl

Tags: java, http

I am playing with the OANDA API.  The documentation states that responses to all successful GET requests will include an ETag header: http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/development-guide/#etag

I have confirmed this is the case when I have a successful request with Curl:

```
$ curl -i "https://api-sandbox.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.7.0.1
Date: Fri, 26 Dec 2014 17:27:01 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 139
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "6a6e222a3f90df8f333ff2a6edfb603e4a354905"

{
        "prices" : [
                {
                        "instrument" : "EUR_USD",
                        "time" : "2014-12-26T17:26:12.336249Z",
                        "bid" : 1.24105,
                        "ask" : 1.24119
                }
        ]
}
```

When, however, I have a successful request with HttpClient `org.apache.httpcomponents 4.3`, the Content-Length and ETag headers are not included.

```
2014-12-26 17:27:54 INFO  RestClient:91 - Executing request: GET https://api-sandbox.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD HTTP/1.1
2014-12-26 17:27:55 INFO  RestClient:103 - Response OK, processing...
2014-12-26 17:27:55 INFO  RestClient:108 - {
    "prices" : [
        {
            "instrument" : "EUR_USD",
            "time" : "2014-12-26T17:28:01.935790Z",
            "bid" : 1.241,
            "ask" : 1.24117
        }
    ]
}
2014-12-26 17:27:55 INFO  RestClient:110 - Headers: [Server: openresty/1.7.0.1, Date: Fri, 26 Dec 2014 17:28:14 GMT, Content-Type: application/json, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Connection: keep-alive]
```

I am missing the ETag and Content-Length headers when I log all the headers received in response to my Java GET request.

I would like to use the ETag header in my Java code, so please can you help me understand why it is not returned.

Comment: I don't get them in the browser either.

Comment: I disabled compression in my httpClient and then received these tags.  This looks similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155638/missing-content-length-header-when-using-nginx-gzip-unicorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient enabled compression by default and the OANDA API does not support ETags when compression is enabled:

```
Note: ETags can not be used in conjunction with compressed responses.
```